# xkcd style graphs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

[image: xkcd-style graph]

So talented people have figured out how to make [xkcd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xkcd) style graphs [in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs), [in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex), [in Python](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/3835181/) and [in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/xkcd-style-graphs-in-r) already.

How can one use MATLAB to produce a plot that looks like the one above?

#### What I have tried

I created wiggly lines, but I couldn't get wiggly axes. The only solution I thought of was to overwrite them with wiggly lines, but I want to be able to change the actual axes. I also could not get the Humor font to work, the code bit used was:

```
 annotation('textbox',[left+left/8 top+0.65*top 0.05525 0.065],...
'String',{'EMBARRASSMENT'},...
'FontSize',24,...
'FontName','Humor',...
'FitBoxToText','off',...
'LineStyle','none');
```

For the wiggly line, I experimented with adding a small random noise and smoothing:

```
 smooth(0.05*randn(size(x)),10)
```

But I couldn't make the white background the appears around them when they intersect...

Comment: Edit seems to satisfy "did some basic research first". Also, the answers here are nice. Re-opening.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I see two ways to solve this: The first way is to add some jitter to the x/y coordinates of the plot features. This has the advantage that you can easily modify a plot, but you have to draw the axes yourself if you want to have them xkcdyfied (see [@Rody Oldenhuis' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12711092/232610)). The second way is to create a non-jittery plot, and use `imtransform` to apply a random distortion to the image. This has the advantage that you can use it with any plot, but you will end up with an image, not an editable plot.

I'll show #2 first, and my attempt at #1 below (if you like #1 better, look at [Rody's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12711092/232610)!).

[image]

This solution relies on two key functions: [EXPORT_FIG](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) from the file exchange to get an anti-aliased screenshot, and [IMTRANSFORM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html) to get a transformation.

```
%# define plot data
x = 1:0.1:10;
y1 = sin(x).*exp(-x/3) + 3;
y2 = 3*exp(-(x-7).^2/2) + 1;

%# plot
fh = figure('color','w');
hold on
plot(x,y1,'b','lineWidth',3);
plot(x,y2,'w','lineWidth',7);
plot(x,y2,'r','lineWidth',3);

xlim([0.95 10])
ylim([0 5])
set(gca,'fontName','Comic Sans MS','fontSize',18,'lineWidth',3,'box','off')

%# add an annotation 
 annotation(fh,'textarrow',[0.4 0.55],[0.8 0.65],...
     'string',sprintf('text%shere',char(10)),'headStyle','none','lineWidth',1.5,...
     'fontName','Comic Sans MS','fontSize',14,'verticalAlignment','middle','horizontalAlignment','left')

%# capture with export_fig
im = export_fig('-nocrop',fh);

%# add a bit of border to avoid black edges
im = padarray(im,[15 15 0],255);

%# make distortion grid
sfc = size(im);
[yy,xx]=ndgrid(1:7:sfc(1),1:7:sfc(2));
pts = [xx(:),yy(:)];
tf = cp2tform(pts+randn(size(pts)),pts,'lwm',12);
w = warning;
warning off images:inv_lwm:cannotEvaluateTransfAtSomeOutputLocations
imt = imtransform(im,tf);
warning(w)

%# remove padding
imt = imt(16:end-15,16:end-15,:);

figure('color','w')
imshow(imt)
```

---

Here's my initial attempt at jittering

[image]

```
%# define plot data
x = 1:0.1:10;
y1 = sin(x).*exp(-x/3) + 3;
y2 = 3*exp(-(x-7).^2/2) + 1;

%# jitter
x = x+randn(size(x))*0.01;
y1 = y1+randn(size(x))*0.01;
y2 = y2+randn(size(x))*0.01;

%# plot
figure('color','w')
hold on
plot(x,y1,'b','lineWidth',3);
plot(x,y2,'w','lineWidth',7);
plot(x,y2,'r','lineWidth',3);

xlim([0.95 10])
ylim([0 5])
set(gca,'fontName','Comic Sans MS','fontSize',18,'lineWidth',3,'box','off')
```

Comment: Enjoy your time on SO [while you can!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41889/52738) ;)

Comment: @gnovice: It'll be my third one. I hope I have it pretty much figured out by now :)

Comment: @Jonas good job! I think your #2 got the right feel for the wiggles, among all solutions so far. However, it still misses the big wiggly ticks, a frame around the text, and hand drawn curved lines to point from the text to a line...

Comment: +1 for EXPORT_FIG. Turning all my graphs more pleasing thanks to anti-aliasing.

Comment: Requires image processing toolbox in case anyone struggles.

Comment: @JasonS: sorry, it was the closest I had available at the time.

Answer (score 97):

Rather than re-implementing all the various plotting functions I wanted to create a generic tool that could convert any existing plot to a xkcd style plot.

This approach means that you can create plots and style them using standard [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) functions and then when you're done you can then re-render the plot in an xkcd style while preserving the overall style of the plot.

### Examples

**Plot**
[image]

**Bar & Plot**

[image]

**Box & Plot**
[image]

### How it works

The function works by iterating over the children of an axes. If the children are of type `line` or `patch` it distorts them slightly. If the child is of type `hggroup` it then iterates on the sub-children of the `hggroup`. I have plans to support other plot types, such as `image`, but it's not clear what is the best way to distort image to have an xkcd style.

Finally to ensure that the distortions look uniform (that is, short lines aren't distored more than long lines), I measure the line length in pixels and then up sample proportional to its length. I then add noise to every Nth sample which produces lines that have more or less the same amount of distortion.

### The Code

Rather than pasting several hundred lines of code I'll just link to a [gist of the source](https://gist.github.com/3834337). Additionally the source code and the code to generate the above examples are freely available [GitHub](https://github.com/slayton/matlab-xkcdify).

As you can see from the examples, it doesn't yet distort the axes themselves although I plan to implement as soon as I figure out the best way to do that.

Comment: Nice! I have been working a similar piece of code that implements the `export_fig` route, i.e. it first formats the plot xkcd-like, and then distorts the picture.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really proud of the box plots. I was surprised at the level of hacking required to get those plots to show up.

Comment: I will use it to convert my entire presentation into a XKCD style.

Comment: Hi Slayton, those are fantastic! I have just one question, is there a way to also make the axes cartoony/xkcd-ish? That would do it for me and I would be able to use it! :-) Many thanks...

Comment: @Learnaholic AFAIK matlab doesn't provide any api's (documented or undocumented) to change the way that axes are rendered

Comment: @slayton - use standard plot window commands to NOT plot axes, then draw wiggly lines  like  x = 0:100, y = 0 + random(101,1)/20

Comment: doesn't change line width for me matlab r2017b

Answer (score 66):

The first step... find a system font you like (use the function [`listfonts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/listfonts.html) to see what's available) or install one that matches the handwriting style from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/). I found a ["Humor Sans"](http://antiyawn.com/uploads/Humor-Sans.ttf) TrueType font from user ch00f mentioned in [this blog post](http://xkcdsucks.blogspot.com/2009/03/xkcdsucks-is-proud-to-present-humor.html), and will use it for my subsequent examples.

As I see it, you'll generally need three different modified graphics objects to make these sorts of graphs: an [axes object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html), a [line object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html), and a [text object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html). You might also want an [annotation object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) to make things easier, but I forewent that for now as it could be more difficult to implement than the above three objects.

I created wrapper functions that created the three objects, overriding certain property settings to make them more xkcd-like. One limitation is that the new graphics they produce won't be updated in certain cases (like bounding boxes on text objects when resizing the axes), but that could be accounted for with a more complete object-oriented implementation that involves inheriting from the [handle class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.html), using [events and listeners](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners--concepts.html), etc. For now, here are my simpler implementations:

xkcd_axes.m:

```
function hAxes = xkcd_axes(xkcdOptions, varargin)

  hAxes = axes(varargin{:}, 'NextPlot', 'add', 'Visible', 'off', ...
               'XLimMode', 'manual', 'YLimMode', 'manual');

  axesUnits = get(hAxes, 'Units');
  set(hAxes, 'Units', 'pixels');
  axesPos = get(hAxes, 'Position');
  set(hAxes, 'Units', axesUnits);
  xPoints = round(axesPos(3)/10);
  yPoints = round(axesPos(4)/10);
  limits = [xlim(hAxes) ylim(hAxes)];
  ranges = [abs(limits(2) - limits(1)) abs(limits(4) - limits(3))];
  backColor = get(get(hAxes, 'Parent'), 'Color');
  xColor = get(hAxes, 'XColor');
  yColor = get(hAxes, 'YColor');
  line('Parent', hAxes, 'Color', xColor, 'LineWidth', 3, ...
       'Clipping', 'off', ...
       'XData', linspace(limits(1), limits(2), xPoints), ...
       'YData', limits(3) + rand(1, xPoints).*0.005.*ranges(2));
  line('Parent', hAxes, 'Color', yColor, 'LineWidth', 3, ...
       'Clipping', 'off', ...
       'YData', linspace(limits(3), limits(4), yPoints), ...
       'XData', limits(1) + rand(1, yPoints).*0.005.*ranges(1));

  xTicks = get(hAxes, 'XTick');
  if ~isempty(xTicks)
    yOffset = limits(3) - 0.05.*ranges(2);
    tickIndex = true(size(xTicks));
    if ismember('left', xkcdOptions)
      tickIndex(1) = false;
      xkcd_arrow('left', [limits(1) + 0.02.*ranges(1) xTicks(1)], ...
                 yOffset, xColor);
    end
    if ismember('right', xkcdOptions)
      tickIndex(end) = false;
      xkcd_arrow('right', [xTicks(end) limits(2) - 0.02.*ranges(1)], ...
                 yOffset, xColor);
    end
    plot([1; 1]*xTicks(tickIndex), ...
         0.5.*[-yOffset; yOffset]*ones(1, sum(tickIndex)), ...
         'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', xColor, 'LineWidth', 3, ...
         'Clipping', 'off');
    xLabels = cellstr(get(hAxes, 'XTickLabel'));
    for iLabel = 1:numel(xLabels)
      xkcd_text(xTicks(iLabel), yOffset, xLabels{iLabel}, ...
                'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
                'VerticalAlignment', 'middle', ...
                'BackgroundColor', backColor);
    end
  end

  yTicks = get(hAxes, 'YTick');
  if ~isempty(yTicks)
    xOffset = limits(1) - 0.05.*ranges(1);
    tickIndex = true(size(yTicks));
    if ismember('down', xkcdOptions)
      tickIndex(1) = false;
      xkcd_arrow('down', xOffset, ...
                 [limits(3) + 0.02.*ranges(2) yTicks(1)], yColor);
    end
    if ismember('up', xkcdOptions)
      tickIndex(end) = false;
      xkcd_arrow('up', xOffset, ...
                 [yTicks(end) limits(4) - 0.02.*ranges(2)], yColor);
    end
    plot(0.5.*[-xOffset; xOffset]*ones(1, sum(tickIndex)), ...
         [1; 1]*yTicks(tickIndex), ...
         'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', yColor, 'LineWidth', 3, ...
         'Clipping', 'off');
    yLabels = cellstr(get(hAxes, 'YTickLabel'));
    for iLabel = 1:numel(yLabels)
      xkcd_text(xOffset, yTicks(iLabel), yLabels{iLabel}, ...
                'HorizontalAlignment', 'right', ...
                'VerticalAlignment', 'middle', ...
                'BackgroundColor', backColor);
    end
  end

  function xkcd_arrow(arrowType, xArrow, yArrow, arrowColor)
    if ismember(arrowType, {'left', 'right'})
      xLine = linspace(xArrow(1), xArrow(2), 10);
      yLine = yArrow + rand(1, 10).*0.003.*ranges(2);
      arrowScale = 0.05.*ranges(1);
      if strcmp(arrowType, 'left')
        xArrow = xLine(1) + arrowScale.*[0 0.5 1 1 1 0.5];
        yArrow = yLine(1) + arrowScale.*[0 0.125 0.25 0 -0.25 -0.125];
      else
        xArrow = xLine(end) - arrowScale.*[0 0.5 1 1 1 0.5];
        yArrow = yLine(end) + arrowScale.*[0 -0.125 -0.25 0 0.25 0.125];
      end
    else
      xLine = xArrow + rand(1, 10).*0.003.*ranges(1);
      yLine = linspace(yArrow(1), yArrow(2), 10);
      arrowScale = 0.05.*ranges(2);
      if strcmp(arrowType, 'down')
        xArrow = xLine(1) + arrowScale.*[0 0.125 0.25 0 -0.25 -0.125];
        yArrow = yLine(1) + arrowScale.*[0 0.5 1 1 1 0.5];
      else
        xArrow = xLine(end) + arrowScale.*[0 -0.125 -0.25 0 0.25 0.125];
        yArrow = yLine(end) - arrowScale.*[0 0.5 1 1 1 0.5];
      end
    end
    line('Parent', hAxes, 'Color', arrowColor, 'LineWidth', 3, ...
         'Clipping', 'off', 'XData', xLine, 'YData', yLine);
    patch('Parent', hAxes, 'FaceColor', arrowColor, ...
          'EdgeColor', arrowColor, 'LineWidth', 2, 'Clipping', 'off', ...
          'XData', xArrow + [0 rand(1, 5).*0.002.*ranges(1)], ...
          'YData', yArrow + [0 rand(1, 5).*0.002.*ranges(2)]);
  end

end
```

xkcd_text.m:

```
function hText = xkcd_text(varargin)

  hText = text(varargin{:});
  set(hText, 'FontName', 'Humor Sans', 'FontSize', 13, ...
      'FontWeight', 'normal');

  backColor = get(hText, 'BackgroundColor');
  edgeColor = get(hText, 'EdgeColor');
  if ~strcmp(backColor, 'none') || ~strcmp(edgeColor, 'none')
    hParent = get(hText, 'Parent');
    extent = get(hText, 'Extent');
    nLines = size(get(hText, 'String'), 1);
    extent = extent + [-0.5 -0.5 1 1].*0.25.*extent(4)./nLines;
    yPoints = 5*nLines;
    xPoints = round(yPoints*extent(3)/extent(4));
    noiseScale = 0.05*extent(4)/nLines;
    set(hText, 'BackgroundColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', 'none');
    xBox = [linspace(extent(1), extent(1) + extent(3), xPoints) ...
            extent(1) + extent(3) + noiseScale.*rand(1, yPoints) ...
            linspace(extent(1) + extent(3), extent(1), xPoints) ...
            extent(1) + noiseScale.*rand(1, yPoints)];
    yBox = [extent(2) + noiseScale.*rand(1, xPoints) ...
            linspace(extent(2), extent(2) + extent(4), yPoints) ...
            extent(2) + extent(4) + noiseScale.*rand(1, xPoints) ...
            linspace(extent(2) + extent(4), extent(2), yPoints)];
    patch('Parent', hParent, 'FaceColor', backColor, ...
          'EdgeColor', edgeColor, 'LineWidth', 2, 'Clipping', 'off', ...
          'XData', xBox, 'YData', yBox);
    hKids = get(hParent, 'Children');
    set(hParent, 'Children', [hText; hKids(hKids ~= hText)]);
  end

end
```

xkcd_line.m:

```
function hLine = xkcd_line(xData, yData, varargin)

  yData = yData + 0.01.*max(range(xData), range(yData)).*rand(size(yData));
  line(xData, yData, varargin{:}, 'Color', 'w', 'LineWidth', 8);
  hLine = line(xData, yData, varargin{:}, 'LineWidth', 3);

end
```

And here's a sample script that uses these to recreate the above comic. I recreated the lines by using [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) to mark points in the plot with the mouse, capturing them, then plotting them how I wanted:

```
xS = [0.0359 0.0709 0.1004 0.1225 0.1501 0.1759 0.2219 0.2477 0.2974 0.3269 0.3582 0.3895 0.4061 0.4337 0.4558 0.4797 0.5074 0.5276 0.5589 0.5810 0.6013 0.6179 0.6271 0.6344 0.6381 0.6418 0.6529 0.6713 0.6842 0.6934 0.7026 0.7118 0.7265 0.7376 0.7560 0.7726 0.7836 0.7965 0.8149 0.8370 0.8573 0.8867 0.9033 0.9346 0.9659 0.9843 0.9936];
yS = [0.2493 0.2520 0.2548 0.2548 0.2602 0.2629 0.2629 0.2657 0.2793 0.2657 0.2575 0.2575 0.2602 0.2629 0.2657 0.2766 0.2793 0.2875 0.3202 0.3856 0.4619 0.5490 0.6771 0.7670 0.7970 0.8270 0.8433 0.8433 0.8243 0.7180 0.6199 0.5272 0.4510 0.4128 0.3392 0.2711 0.2275 0.1757 0.1485 0.1131 0.1022 0.0858 0.0858 0.1022 0.1267 0.1567 0.1594];

xF = [0.0304 0.0488 0.0727 0.0967 0.1335 0.1630 0.2090 0.2348 0.2698 0.3011 0.3269 0.3545 0.3803 0.4153 0.4466 0.4724 0.4945 0.5110 0.5350 0.5516 0.5608 0.5700 0.5755 0.5810 0.5884 0.6013 0.6179 0.6363 0.6492 0.6584 0.6676 0.6731 0.6842 0.6860 0.6934 0.7007 0.7136 0.7265 0.7394 0.7560 0.7726 0.7818 0.8057 0.8444 0.8794 0.9107 0.9475 0.9751 0.9917];
yF = [0.0804 0.0940 0.0967 0.1049 0.1185 0.1458 0.1512 0.1540 0.1649 0.1812 0.1812 0.1703 0.1621 0.1594 0.1703 0.1975 0.2411 0.3065 0.3801 0.4782 0.5708 0.6526 0.7452 0.8106 0.8324 0.8488 0.8433 0.8270 0.7888 0.7343 0.6826 0.5981 0.5300 0.4782 0.3910 0.3420 0.2847 0.2248 0.1621 0.0995 0.0668 0.0395 0.0232 0.0177 0.0204 0.0232 0.0259 0.0204 0.0232];

xE = [0.0267 0.0488 0.0856 0.1409 0.1759 0.2164 0.2514 0.3011 0.3269 0.3637 0.3969 0.4245 0.4503 0.4890 0.5313 0.5608 0.5939 0.6344 0.6694 0.6934 0.7192 0.7394 0.7523 0.7689 0.7891 0.8131 0.8481 0.8757 0.9070 0.9346 0.9604 0.9807 0.9936];
yE = [0.0232 0.0232 0.0232 0.0259 0.0259 0.0259 0.0313 0.0259 0.0259 0.0259 0.0368 0.0395 0.0477 0.0586 0.0777 0.0886 0.1213 0.1730 0.2466 0.2902 0.3638 0.5082 0.6499 0.7916 0.8924 0.9414 0.9550 0.9387 0.9060 0.8760 0.8542 0.8379 0.8188];

hFigure = figure('Position', [300 300 700 450], 'Color', 'w');
hAxes = xkcd_axes({'left', 'right'}, 'XTick', [0.45 0.60 0.7 0.8], ...
                  'XTickLabel', {'YARD', 'STEPS', 'DOOR', 'INSIDE'}, ...
                  'YTick', []);

hSpeed = xkcd_line(xS, yS, 'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', [0.5 0.5 0.5]);
hFear = xkcd_line(xF, yF, 'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', [0 0.5 1]);
hEmb = xkcd_line(xE, yE, 'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', 'r');

hText = xkcd_text(0.27, 0.9, ...
                  {'WALKING BACK TO MY'; 'FRONT DOOR AT NIGHT:'}, ...
                  'Parent', hAxes, 'EdgeColor', 'k', ...
                  'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');

hSpeedNote = xkcd_text(0.36, 0.35, {'FORWARD'; 'SPEED'}, ...
                       'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', 'k', ...
                       'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
hSpeedLine = xkcd_line([0.4116 0.4282 0.4355 0.4411], ...
                       [0.3392 0.3256 0.3038 0.2820], ...
                       'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', 'k');
hFearNote = xkcd_text(0.15, 0.45, {'FEAR'; 'THAT THERE''S'; ...
                                   'SOMETHING'; 'BEIND ME'}, ...
                      'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', 'k', ...
                      'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
hFearLine = xkcd_line([0.1906 0.1998 0.2127 0.2127 0.2201 0.2256], ...
                      [0.3501 0.3093 0.2629 0.2221 0.1975 0.1676], ...
                      'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', 'k');
hEmbNote = xkcd_text(0.88, 0.45, {'EMBARRASSMENT'}, ...
                     'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', 'k', ...
                     'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
hEmbLine = xkcd_line([0.8168 0.8094 0.7983 0.7781 0.7578], ...
                     [0.4864 0.5436 0.5872 0.6063 0.6226], ...
                     'Parent', hAxes, 'Color', 'k');
```

And *(trumpets)* here's the resulting plot!:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! my only comment is that the lines that point from text should be thinner and more curved (less wiggly).

Comment: This is fantastic, although the plot suffers from aliasing.  I wrote a brief post about how to deal with that here: http://hugocarr.com/index/xkcd-style-graphs-in-matlab/

Answer (score 29):

OK then, here's my less-crude-but-still-not-quite-there-yet attempt:

```
%# init
%# ------------------------

noise = @(x,A) A*randn(size(x));
ns    = @(x,A) A*ones(size(x));


h = figure(2); clf, hold on
pos = get(h, 'position');
set(h, 'position', [pos(1:2) 800 450]);


blackline = {
    'k', ...
    'linewidth', 2};
axisline = {
    'k', ...
    'linewidth', 3};

textprops = {
    'fontName','Comic Sans MS',...
    'fontSize', 14,...
    'lineWidth',3};


%# Plot data
%# ------------------------
x  = 1:0.1:10;

y0 = sin(x).*exp(-x/30) + 3;
y1 = sin(x).*exp(-x/3) + 3;
y2 = 3*exp(-(x-7).^6/.05) + 1;

y0 = y0 + noise(x, 0.01);
y1 = y1 + noise(x, 0.01);
y2 = y2 + noise(x, 0.01);

%# plot
plot(x,y0, 'color', [0.7 0.7 0.7], 'lineWidth',3);

plot(x,y1, 'w','lineWidth',7);
plot(x,y1, 'b','lineWidth',3);

plot(x,y2, 'w','lineWidth',7);
plot(x,y2, 'r','lineWidth',3);




%# text
%# ------------------------
ll(1) = text(1.3, 4.2,...
    {'Walking back to my'
    'front door at night:'});

ll(2) = text(5, 0.7, 'yard');
ll(3) = text(6.2, 0.7, 'steps');
ll(4) = text(7, 0.7, 'door');
ll(5) = text(8, 0.7, 'inside');

set(ll, textprops{:});


%# arrows & lines
%# ------------------------

%# box around "walking back..."
xx = 1.2:0.1:3.74;
yy = ns(xx, 4.6) + noise(xx, 0.007);
plot(xx, yy, blackline{:})

xx = 1.2:0.1:3.74;
yy = ns(xx, 3.8) + noise(xx, 0.007);
plot(xx, yy, blackline{:})

yy = 3.8:0.1:4.6;
xx = ns(yy, 1.2) + noise(yy, 0.007);
plot(xx, yy, blackline{:})

xx = ns(yy, 3.74) + noise(yy, 0.007);
plot(xx, yy, blackline{:})

%# left arrow
x_arr = 1.2:0.1:4.8;
y_arr = 0.65 * ones(size(x_arr)) + noise(x_arr, 0.005);
plot(x_arr, y_arr, blackline{:})
x_head = [1.1 1.6 1.62];
y_head = [0.65 0.72 0.57];
patch(x_head, y_head, 'k')

%# right arrow
x_arr = 8.7:0.1:9.8;
y_arr = 0.65 * ones(size(x_arr)) + noise(x_arr, 0.005);
plot(x_arr, y_arr, blackline{:})
x_head = [9.8 9.3 9.3];
y_head = [0.65 0.72 0.57];
patch(x_head, y_head, 'k')

%# left line on axis
y_line = 0.8:0.1:1.1;
x_line = ns(y_line, 6.5) + noise(y_line, 0.005);
plot(x_line, y_line, blackline{:})

%# right line on axis
y_line = 0.8:0.1:1.1;
x_line = ns(y_line, 7.2) + noise(y_line, 0.005);
plot(x_line, y_line, blackline{:})

%# axes
x_xax = x;
y_xax = 0.95 + noise(x_xax, 0.01);
y_yax = 0.95:0.1:5;
x_yax = x(1) + noise(y_yax, 0.01);
plot(x_xax, y_xax, axisline{:})
plot(x_yax, y_yax, axisline{:})


% finalize 
%# ------------------------

xlim([0.95 10])
ylim([0 5])
axis off
```

Result:

[image: XKCD imitation in Matlab]

Things to do:

1. Find better functions (better define them piece-wise)
2. Add "annotations" and wavy lines to the curves they describe
3. Find a better font than Comic Sans!
4. Generalize everything into a function `plot2xkcd` so that we can convert *any* plot/figure to the xkcd style.

Comment: Nice job with colors and axes! I do feel that they're a little too jittery, though. +1 anyway.

Comment: @HighPerormanceMark: I *still* don't think this is all very useful, however, it's great fun :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis why not useful? I find the styled plots better looking than the original plots.  Adding style is certainly a valid function.

Comment: @slayton: Let's take one very advanced number crunching tool that was designed to be super-efficient, capable of making beautiful, publish-ready plots as precisely as possible, and let's use it to make...**comics** with it. Sorry, that's just silly. It's *great fun* however, which is why most people here upvoted and what got the question re-opened. Will this be of any use to future visitors? Well...it *does* inspire. Perhaps it will invite some people to learn Matlab. But making xkcd-style work properly will require hacks and techniques that are uhm...questionable at the very least :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I, for one, will use these graphs in my presentations. And it's usually with the "hacks" that you really learn how the environment works.