# Cartoonish style plots in MATLAB or Python?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot

There is an excellent post on [Mathematica here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs) on how to make plots and graphs more cartoony and warm to an audience.

I was wondering if anyone knows of similar ways we can do this in either MATLAB, or possibly python. Is something like this possible? (It is also known as xkcd-style plots)

Comment: Previous question with many answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701841/xkcd-style-graphs-in-matlab

Comment: @Navan Ah shoot, how did I miss that in the search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is (in Python at least)!

here's a simple example (basically ripped from a pyplot tutorial):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

plt.xkcd(scale=1, length=100, randomness=2)

plt.plot(t, t, 'r', t, t**2, 'b', t, t**3, 'g')
plt.show()
```

just make sure you have a recent enough version of matplotlib and you should be good to go

here's the docs on the xkcd function - http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xkcd#matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd

when I run the code above on my computer I see:

[image]

Comment: Wow! I think you have finally convinced me to take up Python! :-)

Comment: Can you actually make those same type of plots/figures you see in the mathematica post?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/xkcd/gallery.html.  This is a bunch of xkcd type plots made in matplotlib.  I didn't see the exact one that was from the post, but yes, I am certain that you could make it.

Comment: I don't see why not.  It's just a different series to define the curve (adjust the numpy array) and then adding comments.  Comments can be added thusly: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html (per the link I embedded you may need to get a different font though to really make it look good)