# Stopwatch function in Julia

Tags: julia

In MATLAB, there are a pair of functions `tic` and `toc`
which can be used to start and stop a stopwatch timer.
An example taken from [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html):

```
tic
A = rand(12000, 4400);
B = rand(12000, 4400);
toc
C = A'.*B';
toc
```

I am aware that there is a macro `@time` in Julia
that has similar functionality.

```
julia> @time [sin(cos(i)) for i in 1:100000];
elapsed time: 0.00721026 seconds (800048 bytes allocated)
```

Is there a set of similar functions in Julia?
The `@time` macro works well for timing statements
that can be written in one or two lines.
For longer portions of code,
I would prefer to use tic-toc functions.

#### What I tried

When I googled "julia stopwatch",
I found one useful link and four unrelated links.

1. Introducing Julia/Metaprogramming - Wikibooks, open ...
   Meta-programming is when you write Julia code to process and modify Julia code. ... The @time macro inserts a "start the stopwatch" command at the beginning  ...
2. Our Invisible Stopwatch promo - YouTube
   Video for julia stopwatch
3. Julia Larson on Twitter: "This #Mac OSX timer/stopwatch is ...
4. Timing episodes of The French Chef with a stopwatch
5. julia griffith | Oiselle Running Apparel for Women

I don't know why I hadn't thought of just trying `tic()` and `toc()`.

Comment: Julia has `tic()` and `toc()` too... However, please do read the Julia Performance Tips http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#performance-tips ... The tl;dr is that you will be best off putting your computation inside of a function rather than doing everything at global scope, after which using `@time` will be simple. `@time` is also advantageous in that it reports memory allocation in addition to time.

Comment: I don't see why this deserved a down-vote (maybe the extraneous material in the "What I tried section?). Overly harsh. +1 back to 0. Also, I strongly second Isaiah's comment. 90% of the "Why is my Julia slow" questions occur because the author is working in global scope, ie did not wrap code inside a function.

Comment: @ColinTBowers I had actually received two downvotes. My guess is that cause was that the downvoters were upset that I did not just try `tic()` and `toc()`. I later added the "What I tried" section to explain why it was not obvious to me when I searched that the functions `tic()` and `toc()` actually exited in Julia.

Comment: Understood. A "What I tried" section is usually a good idea, and making it explicit like you have is even better. Of course, sometimes people can get a bit silly. I remember when [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701841/xkcd-style-graphs-in-matlab) was closed because it didn't initially contain a "what I have tried" section...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a [search](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/search/?q=tic&check_keywords=yes&area=default#) of the [Julia documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/?highlight=tic#Base.tic)

> `tic()`
>
> Set a timer to be read by the next call to `toc()` or `toq()`. The
>   macro call `@time expr` can also be used to time evaluation.

Comment: as Julia has changed since you answered, the links to the docs are dead and the  `tic` and `toc` have been deprecated. If you could, it would be great to update it. Thanks.

Comment: tic() has been depreciated

Answer (score 8):

`tic()` and `toc()` have been deprecated as of https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/1b023388f49e13e7a42a899c12602d0fd5d60b0a

You can use `@elapsed` and `@time` for longer chunks by wrapping them in an environment, like so:

```
t = @elapsed begin
    ...
end
```

There is also [TickTock.jl](https://github.com/cormullion/TickTock.jl), which has reimplemented `tic()` and `toc()` and `tick()` and `tock()`.

```
using TickTock
tick()
# Started timer at 2017-12-13T22:30:59.632
tock()
# 55.052638936 ms: 55 seconds, 52 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `time()` to get similar output. For example:

```
t = time()

# code block here
# ...
# ...

dt = time() - t
```