# xkcd style graph - error with registered fonts

Tags: r

I want to create the graph, like at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/how-can-we-make-xkcd-style-graphs-in-r/13985143#comment19302007_13985143) for the previous topic, but receive error:

> In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : Font
>   family not found in Windows font database

Though `fonts()` shows "Humor Sans" and "xksd" are installed. I use Windows 7 64bit, R 2.15.2 RStudio 0.96.331.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with OSX but this isn't working.

Comment: Thank you. I also stuck on the same issue. Thanks for your kind solution and help. Just want to add one comment for beginners, i.e. before run font_import() you have to load library(extrafont) Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I had the same problem some time ago. Here is what I did:

1. Put Humor-Sans font file into your project folder and make sure your working directory is set to the same.
2. Import the fonts (this might take a while) by calling

   ```
   font_import()
   ```
3. Look through the list of fonts and see if you can find Humor-Sans by

   ```
   fonts()
   ```
4. Load the fonts

   ```
   loadfonts(device = "win")
   ```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Bingo. Thank you very much. I think loadfonts(device="win") is the solution.