# Humor Sans in R

Tags: r, fonts

When trying to install Humor Sans [as per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12680311), I run

```
font_import(".")
```

and receive the following warning:

```
Found FontName for 1 fonts.
Scanning afm files in C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library/extrafontdb/metrics
Writing font table in C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library/extrafontdb/fontmap/fonttable.csv
Writing Fontmap to C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library/extrafontdb/fontmap/Fontmap...
Warning message:
In readLines(fd, 30) :
  seek on a gzfile connection returned an internal error
```

I've tried several different ways to get the font to work, but I think this must be the error. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to remedy this?

I'm running Windows XP.

Comment: why not use the defaults: font_import()?

Comment: @EDi that command doesn't find the Humor-Sans.tff file, it only loads in the existing windows fonts.

Comment: You're not going crazy (or at least if you are, you've got company)!  I'm also on Windows XP, and have *never* been able to get those fonts properly loaded, despite trying several times and despite [this additional post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989644/xkcd-style-graph-error-with-registered-fonts?lq=1) which helped some Windows users...

Comment: I am not on windows, perhabs ttf_import() may also do the job?

Comment: @EDi -- Thanks, but nope. `ttf_import()` exhibits the same error.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks, there must be a way to do this!