# Error in font_import while installing xkcd font

Tags: r

I was trying to install the xkcd font for R on my Mac following the instructions in `vignette("xkcd-intro")`

```
> download.file("http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf", dest="xkcd.ttf", mode="wb")
essai de l'URL 'http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf'
Content type 'application/x-font-ttf' length 12712 bytes (12 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 12 KB

> system("mkdir ~/.fonts")
> system("cp xkcd.ttf  ~/.fonts")
```

Until here, all seems to be ok be I have an error with the following call to `font import`:

```
> font_import(pattern = "[X/x]kcd", prompt=FALSE)
Scanning ttf files in /Library/Fonts/, /System/Library/Fonts, ~/Library/Fonts/ ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

How can I fix that? Is there another way to install these font?

I already looked at questions here about R and xkcd font like [Not able to install xkcd fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231246/not-able-to-install-xkcd-fonts/)
 and [xkcd style graph - error with registered fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989644/xkcd-style-graph-error-with-registered-fonts)
 but it's not the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-detected path in `font_import` was wrong. To fix it:

```
font_import(path = "~/.fonts", pattern = "[X/x]kcd", prompt=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me. I noticed that the fonts were being searched for in the wrong directory. In my case, there was the message,

```
    Scanning ttf files in C:\Windows\Fonts ...
```

So, I changed the command to look in my working directory...

Old version

```
        font_import(pattern = "[X/x]kcd", prompt=FALSE)
```

New version

```
        font_import(paths = getwd(), pattern = "[X/x]kcd", prompt=FALSE)
```

Success! Hope it works for you too.