# Not able to install xkcd fonts

Tags: r

I was trying the xkcd font as per the instructions given in the vignette: `vignette("xkcd-intro")`

However get an error on the following step:

```
> system("cp xkcd.tff -t ~/.fonts")
cp: xkcd.tff: No such file or directory
cp: -t: No such file or directory
```

What to do??

Comment: Are you running R from the same directory xkcd.tff is in?

Comment: Yes! I tried it from within RStudio (using system()) and from the terminal. Still not working...

Answer (score 5):

1. Are you sure it's not supposed to be `xkcd.ttf` instead of `xkcd.tff`?
2. I'm fairly certain that `cp SOURCE OPTION DESTINATION` is not a legal use of `cp` on any Unix system.  In fact, since you're copying only one file, you don't even need the `-t` option.  It should probably just be `system("cp xkcd.ttf ~/.fonts/")`.

Comment: Thanks. Correct on both accounts! The installation instructions need to be updated. Just [notified the author](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/how-can-we-make-xkcd-style-graphs-in-r/16597217#16597217)!!

Comment: This removed the error, but fonts were not copied!! My own answer is pasted below!!

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to get it to work myself. Essentially, you have to copy the downloaded font file to all the folders in `font.paths()`.

On OS X:

```
for(dirs in font.paths()) {
    file.copy(file.path(dirs,"xkcd.ttf"), "~/Library/Fonts/")
}
```

And it's working!!

Answer (score 0):

@dg99 is correct but the issue is that the filename changes in the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xkcd/xkcd.pdf)

```
download.file("http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf", dest="xkcd.ttf", mode="wb")
system("cp xkcd.tff -t ~/.fonts")
```

Change the second line to:
`system("cp xkcd.ttf -t ~/.fonts")`

Comment: I'm still pretty sure that the `-t` will break on Unix systems.