# Trouble with XKCD package

Tags: r

I am trying to get started with the `xkcd` package, and following the instructions in [the vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xkcd/vignettes/xkcd-intro.pdf). How ever, as soon as I reach the section 2.2 on "Saving the graphs", I get the an error.

Here is the code:

```
font.add("xkcd",  regular = "xkcd.ttf")
p <-  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=wt), data=mtcars) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16, family = "xkcd"))
print(p)
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "xkcd"
2: In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "xkcd"
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Did you install the fonts described in section 2.1?

Comment: Yes!! After a [lot of trouble](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/23231246/not-able-to-install-xkcd-fonts/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to get it to work myself. Essentially, you have to copy the downloaded xkcd.ttf to all the folders in `fon.paths()`.

```
for(dirs in font.paths()) {
file.copy(file.path(dirs,"xkcd.ttf), "/Users/shambho/library/Fonts/")
}
```

And it's working!!

Comment: Scratch that. I had to go into OSX Font Book and fix the font for some reason, then reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a clean install of MacOS Sierra. The following worked for me:

```
## Perform Once:
## install.packages("xkcd", dependencies=TRUE)
## install.packages("sysfonts")
## library(sysfonts)
## download.file("http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf", dest="xkcd.ttf", mode="wb")
## system("cp xkcd.ttf ~/Library/Fonts")
```

Alternatively, get a copy of `xkcd.ttf` and copy it to your local Fonts directory (make sure it's sourced by your system). If things go wrong and all your stackoverflow posts show only question marks, then you've messed up your fonts. Now go to the **Font Book**  and File --> Restore Standard Fonts.

```
## Example 1
library("xkcd")
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(text = element_text(size = 16, family = "xkcd"))
```