# Importing the xkcd fonts in R (for xkcd package) on windows

Tags: r, fonts

I am not used to answer my own question. However, I thought the solution could benefice someone in the future (see answer). It was not possible to post this issue on the package's github (a read-only mirror).

I had a lot of trouble to install the xkcd font in R on windows, especially for recent version of R (4.1.1). There is this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231246/not-able-to-install-xkcd-fonts) on OS, which do not work on windows. It needed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642855/9086725) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733732/cant-change-fonts-in-ggplot-geom-text) (two unrelated questions) to be able to use the font in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I reached.

Download necessary packages.

```
install.packages("extrafont","remotes","xkcd")
library(extrafont)
library(remotes)
```

One of the problem is the error message `In system2(ttf2pt1, c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  :  running command` [...] that is resolved by downgrading `Rttf2pt1` to version 1.3.8

```
remotes::install_version("Rttf2pt1", version = "1.3.8")
```

Download the font and be sure it is in the working directory (it should be).

```
download.file("http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf", dest = "xkcd.ttf", mode = "wb")
```

The original description to import the font does not work (see the `vignette("xkcd-intro"`), the path has to be redirected to the working directory.

```
font_import(paths = getwd(), pattern = "[X/x]kcd", prompt = FALSE)
```

Loading the font and the xkcd package should now work.

```
loadfonts(device = "win")
library(xkcd)
```

The package xkcd and its functions should not work properly.