# Changing Fonts for Graphs in R

Tags: r, graph, fonts

In my study I am generating various graphs using R. I see that most of the graphs come up with a Sans Serif type font with various sizes.

How to I change all the text in a graph (x-label, y-label, title, legend etc.) into a uniform font e.g. Times New Roman, 12pt, Bold?

Comment: Are you using base plot or a specialized plotting package like ggplot2?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the [**extrafont**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/extrafont.pdf) package.

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device="win")       #Register fonts for Windows bitmap output
fonts()                       #vector of font family names
##  [1] "Andale Mono"                  "AppleMyungjo"                
##  [3] "Arial Black"                  "Arial"                       
##  [5] "Arial Narrow"                 "Arial Rounded MT Bold"  

library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +     
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12)) #Times New Roman, 12pt, Bold
#example taken from the Github project page
```

[image]

**Note:** Using the `extrafont` package, you can also embed these fonts in PDF and EPS files (make plots in R and export to PDF/EPS). You can also directly create math symbols (see math equation in plot below), usually created using TeX. More information [**here**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/README.html) and [**here**](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html). Also look at the [**github project page**](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/).

[image]

Also look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12680311/3297280) answer which describes creating [**xkcd**](http://xkcd.com/) style graphs using the `extrafont` package.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

You can change the font in Windows to Times New Roman using the `windowsFonts()` command and the `family` option in `plot`:

```
x = seq(1,10,1)
y = 1.5*x
windowsFonts(A = windowsFont("Times New Roman"))
plot(x, y,
  family="A",
  main = "title",
  font=2)
```

Bold text comes from `font=2`. As for the size, see `?cex()`. Also, see here: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html

[image]

Comment: This solution ONLY works for Times New Roman font. I'm trying to use this solution to change the font to something other than Times New Roman but no matter what I put in the font NEVER changes. What is a person supposed to do if they want a font other than Times New Roman?

Comment: windowsFonts(A = windowsFont("Helvetica"))
plot(forecast(fit, 5), xlab ="Year", 
    ylab ="Passengers", 
    main ="Carnival Cruises: Passenger Volume (In Thousands)", col.main ="darkgreen", 
    xlim = c(2005, 2025), ylim = c(7000, 16000), family="A", las="0")

Answer (score 20):

Here's a `ggplot` solution using `WindowsFonts(...)`

```
windowsFonts(Times=windowsFont("Times New Roman"))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12)) #Times New Roman, 12pt, Bold
```

[image]

As you can see, the text really is Times New Roman.

The main idea is that whatever name you give the font internally in R, using

```
windowsFonts(name=windowsFont("system name"))
```

you should use to reference the font in

```
theme(text=element_text(family="name",...),...)
```

Comment: I think this solution is better! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE 2020**
This can now be solved by using the `ggtext` package, e.g.:

```
install.packages(ggtext)

plot <- plot + theme(
  legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(family = 'Times', face='bold')
)
```

In addition, you can use markdown to complement your plot text. I experienced `ggtext` simpler and more fail safe than `extrafont`.

Comment: this seems not to work for the plot as a whole, i.e. `text = ggtext::element_markdown(family = 'Times')` produces the error message `! Theme element `text` has "NULL" property without default: fill, box.colour, linetype, linewidth, halign, valign, padding, r, align_widths, align_heights, and rotate_margins`