# Changing to Times New Roman in r graph

Tags: r, fonts

```
dose.m1logistic<-drm(adults/number~concentration,weights=number,data=dose,fct=L.3(),type="binomial")
plot(dose.m1logistic,type="all",log="x",xlab="Concentration (ppb)",ylab="Proportion Emergence")
```

I want to plot a graph using this codes in r, the axes font type should be Times New Roman and font type 12

Thanking you in anticipation
Sylvester

Comment: Add `par(family="Times")` before to change the font face

Comment: If the comment answers the question then you should probably delete the question. It's pretty low quality question at the moment because it's not reproducible (although that might be easy to circumvent), and doesn't load the required packages (which means we cannot tell which plotting paradigm is used by `plot.drm`), and doesn't specify your OS (which might affect font names).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Fonts for Graphs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689222/changing-fonts-for-graphs-in-r)