# Why the font does not change when `bquote` is used?

Tags: r

I use the code below to put a formula text in a plot:

```
bb = 0.16
plot(x)
text(1, 1, bquote(I^2== .(bb)), font=6)
```

When `font=6` is used in `text()` without `bquote`, the font changes to 'Times New Romans'. But seems it does not work with `bquote` and the font does not change. Any tips for that?

PS: This question is marked as duplicate to another question related to `extrafont package`. Well, my question is just simply related to `bquot` which does not need any package for writing equations in R plots!

Comment: Try `windowsFonts` as described in e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689222/changing-fonts-for-graphs-in-r/27694671#27694671)

Comment: Yes, this works perfect!