# R - BEST-package - changing font

Tags: r, plot, fonts, bayesian

I try to change the appearance of plots created by the `BEST` package for `R` by changing the displayed font. However, I can only alter the labels with the command `family =`. The difference can be seen in the images below.

If I use `font.axis` or `font.lab` from `par` there will be no compilation with the following error message:

```
Quitting from lines 42-44 (BEST_Package_font.Rmd) 
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) : 
  invalid value specified for graphical parameter "font.lab"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... do.call -> <Anonymous> -> plot.histogram -> plot.window

Execution halted
```

```
library(BEST)

quartzFonts(ubuntu = c("Ubuntu-R", "Ubuntu-I", "Ubuntu-L", "Ubuntu-BI"))

y1 <- c(5.77, 5.33, 4.59, 4.33, 3.66, 4.48)
y2 <- c(3.88, 3.55, 3.29, 2.59, 2.33, 3.59)

BESTout <- BESTmcmc(y1, y2, priors=NULL, parallel=FALSE)

plot(BESTout, which = "mean")

plot(BESTout, which = "mean", family = "Ubuntu-I")
```

I used the family font `Ubuntu` as an example, but this behavior also happens with other fonts. Is there any possibility to change the font of every number and character in the plot?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961247/) a clean solution has been found, which can also be applied to the `BEST` package. Defining fonts like shown above is not necessary.

```
library(BEST)


y1 <- c(5.77, 5.33, 4.59, 4.33, 3.66, 4.48)
y2 <- c(3.88, 3.55, 3.29, 2.59, 2.33, 3.59)

BESTout <- BESTmcmc(y1, y2, priors=NULL, parallel=FALSE)

par(family = "Ubuntu-R")

plot(BESTout, which = "mean")
```

[image]