# R, scatterplot3d: Assigning specific color to group and change font

Tags: r, scatterplot3d

I am relatively new to R. I am trying to plot a 3D scatterplot. I have 4 continuous variables, one of which defines the group. There are 6 groups.
I tried this code:
`scatterplot3d(x,y,z,color=as.numeric(group),pch=20)`
The colors are all too similar. How can I assign specific colors to the 6 groups?
Could you also tell me how to change the font to Calibri?
Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the font part, I'll refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27690022/6478701), which addresses it very well.

For the color part, you have to set up a color palette, and *then* use your numeric `group` variable to access the different colors in the palette.

e.g

```
# make some dummy data
group <- factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 3))
x <- 1:9
y <- rnorm(9) + rep(c(1,-1,1), each=3)

# define a palette (the colors should be in the same order as your group factor levels)
mypalette <- c("grey20", "firebrick", "royalblue") 

plot(x,y, col = mypalette[as.numeric(group)], pch=16, cex=3)
```

yields

[image: plot]

You'll notice I didn't use scatterplot3d, because your question is actually unrelated to that function !

If you want pre-built color palettes, you can have a look at the [`viridis` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html) or the [`RcolorBrewer` package](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/the-a-z-of-rcolorbrewer-palette/).