# Queries about supplementary packages for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a graph with ggplot2, but I need it to look like it's been drawn with crayons or pencils because it's for children. The issue is that ggplot2 only allows me to use pastel colours, but I need to add texture to the graph. I know there was a package in previous versions of R, but in 4.3.1, I'm unfamiliar with it

Which package or code in ggplot2 or in another package do you recommend

Comment: Regarding fonts, what about `if(!("Informal" %in% font_families())) font_add_google("Fuzzy Bubbles", "Informal"); showtext_auto()` and, then, `+ theme(text = element_text(family = "Informal"))`?

Comment: maybe also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/how-can-we-make-xkcd-style-graphs

Comment: Maybe the spongebob or simpsons theme form this package https://ryo-n7.github.io/2019-05-16-introducing-tvthemes-package/

Answer (score 2):

There is the `xkcd` theme https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xkcd/

`ggrough` https://xvrdm.github.io/ggrough/ does not appear activer any more, but used to be another option.